# What descriptive statistics are commonly used for time-series data?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have a time-series of weekly usage data and I'm going to attempt to use some statistics to segment the population.  Skewness and Kurtosis to may allow me to describe the time-series and group the people in different ways.  But I also notice some appear to have saw-tooth patterns, or bimodal patterns, then I don't think these two aforementioned statistics will describe them well.  Distance from the mean would tell me who has continual steady usage vs. unpredictable usage.

What descriptive statistics are commonly used for time-series data?

Thanks,

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about descriptive statistics for time series not about programming.

Comment: Got it, should have posted to stats.stackexchange.com right?  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The periodogram and the autocorrelation function are two common sources of information 
used to analyse and model time series. You can use this information to compare the series.

In the periodogram you can detect the frequencies at which the estimated spectral density is the highest. This will tell you which series are dominated by cycles of the same frequency.

The autocorrelation function (the time domain counterpart of the periodogram) and the partial autocorrelation function can similarly be used to compare and group the series. Those series with significant autocorrelations at the same lag orders could be grouped together.

You may need to transform the series in order to discern some of this information, for example taking differences to render the data stationary. Alternatively you can select an ARIMA model for each series and compare the characteristics of each model (those characteristics will be pretty much the same as those observed in the autocorrelation functions).